# Cannot set ECN bit in python using socket module

Tags: python, sockets

I want to create a tcp server which responds with SYN+ACK with ECN bit in IP header set.

Here's the sample code I have written:

```
# pythonTCPserver.py

import socket

TCP_IP = "127.0.0.1" TCP_PORT = 7979

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TOS, 0x01)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, 5)

iptos = s.getsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TOS) ipttl =
s.getsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL)

print "IP TOS is now set to ", iptos print "IP TTL is not set to ", ipttl

s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print "Connection accepted from :", addr print "Closing connection"

conn.close()
```

When running it and capturing packet on wireshark, I see that TTL is rightly set to 5, but ECN bit is not set, actually the whole TOS section is unchanged.

Any ideas how we can set ECN bit???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can't set the ECN bits using setsockopt. Using the IP_TOS option, you can only set the DSCP bits in the IP header. The two lower bits are ignored. So, using a value of 0x5 instead of 0x1 would set DSCP to 1 and leave the ECN bits unchanged.

Instead, you can use raw sockets, which allow you to specify your own headers, so you can set the ECN bits yourself for each packet. There are plenty of [examples](http://www.binarytides.com/raw-socket-programming-in-python-linux/) of raw sockets out there, or you can look at the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html). Note that you don't have to specify all of the headers. You can choose, for example, to only specify from IP up.

Comment: JFYI, I gave up on this finally, and used tcpreplay to simulate traffic